# Proof based problem related to non-trivial solution of a linear equation system

Tags: algebra-precalculus, determinant

> If the system of linear equations $$a(y+z)-x=0$$ $$b(z+x)-y=0$$$$c(x+y)-z=0$$
>   has a non-trivial solution $(a,b,c \neq -1)$,then show that
>
> $$\frac{1}{1+a}+\frac{1}{1+b}+\frac{1}{1+c}=2$$

**MY ATTEMPT:**

I took this determinant and put it to $0$.

$\begin{vmatrix} -1 & a & a \\ b & -1 & b \\ c & c & -1 \end{vmatrix}=0$

I'm getting $2abc+ab+bc+ca-1=0$ but that is not what is asked for!
Someone help me out !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are already finished, because
$$
\frac{1}{1+a}+\frac{1}{1+b}+\frac{1}{1+c}-2=\frac{ - 2abc - ab - ac - bc + 1}{abc + ab + ac + a + bc + b + c + 1}=0.
$$

Comment: My gosh I did'nt notice that :-P!Phew !

Comment: The first step with the determinant is the important one, so you did very well.